# Скопировать текст из TextView в буфер обмена

Tags: android

Как скопировать текст из TextView в буфер обмена при нажатии на кнопку?

Comment: Да, все правильно.

Comment: @Вероника если вы нашли решение, то либо опубликуйте его в качестве ответа, либо удалите вопрос.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE); 
ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("", textView.getText().toString()); 
clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
```

Comment: Вы можете принять собственный ответ (серая галочка слева), если считаете, что он наиболее полно решает проблему в вашем вопросе.

Comment: Да, но только через два дня пишет что могу